# Python - check if site is blacklisted by google

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is it possible to check if site is blacklisted by google using python? I tried:

```
    try:
            opener = requests.get(strona['url'], headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) \
                AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 \
                Safari/537.36'
            })
            tekst_html = opener.text
```

and search tekst_html for "You are entering the misleading page" or something like that. I realized there is no such phrases in html source. I think it is external script that shows warning.

This is an example of blacklisted site: http://www.forum.dietaproteinowa.eu/

Answer (score 1):

User agent doesn't control what browser displays, it controls what content site sends. Site is blocked by chrome, so chrome engine has to do the blocking. If it was controled by site server, it would be pretty ridiculous: "Hey, look this guy seems to be using chrome, but google said we are blacklisted so we better not send him content, and send that specific blocklisted webpage google gave us"

To check if such site is blacklisted in chrome you basically need to physically run chrome. Thankfully, python can do that for you using `selenium` module with chrome driver.

With selenium you need to run chrome driver, then request driver to open given site, after it is loaded you request source code that selenium received and check if `<html>` tag has `blacklisted` class.

If you do not want browser popping up you can use some selenium specific tricks. For example on linux, you can create virtual display in python and run chrome driver inside that virtual display.